Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS can't connect to certain networks
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Recently I bought a new WiFi router and am currently using it with AP mode, and it seems that my laptop can't connect to that network. It can still connect to my primary router or my school network, so I think it is a software problem (I also dual-boot Windows 11 on the same computer, and it can connect to it without problem).
The icon of the network seems connected, but It says "this site can't be reached" when I try to open a website. Any suggestions? Sorry for my obscure question...
Thanks
